# How to send data back from Activity to Activity with Navigation Component

Tags: android, navigation, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation-graph

I know `Navigation Component` is ideally designed to be used in one-single-activity app. However, Android allows now add `<activity>` items within a `NavGraph`. My app is kind of following the one-single-act pattern, but there is a moment where FragmentA has to navigate a `DialogFragment`.

I would navigate to it by using:

`Navigation.findNavController(v).navigate(R.id.actionToFragmentB);`

**but I cannot because the problem described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67902175/textinpulayout-with-autocompletetextview-shows-shorter-when-dialogfragment)**, so I ended up deciding to navigate to this Fragment by navigating to an ActivityB and placing the Fragment within it by using FragmentTransaction
`Navigation.findNavController(v).navigate(R.id.actionToAcvitityB);`

Summing up, my approach has to navigate from FragmentA within ActivityA to ActivityB, and this last will be in charge of showing the FragmentB by `FragmentTransaction`. Or, I have to navigate from FragmentA within ActivityA to, ¿¿somehow??, FragmentB.

My real problem is: **how do I send data back from ActivityB to ActivityA???** Or from FragmentB to the FragmentA??? Taking into account that having two Activities I do not have the same NavController.

[image]